# Practical One Time Pad Based on Diminished Rate of Random Number Exhaustion

Tags: one-time-pad

One reason why One Time Pads are impractical is that sender and receiver need copies of the same random numbers. This can quickly exhaust the set of numbers if communication is frequent.

Proposal: The set of random numbers kept by pairs of senders and receivers is only the seed values for a shared PRNG. If the seeds are known to sender and receiver thru a shared list then the numbers produced by the PRNG should be identical. If the seeds are ransom then would not the output be random and usable for encoding and decoding?

Process:

In effect, pairs of communicators would share the same list of random seeds. As a message is created, the next random seed is pushed into the PRNG and the numbers produced are used to encode the cipher stream.
The sender's list of shared random numbers is decremented by one.

The receiver looks up the current random number seed and pushes it into the same PRNG. This delivers identical numbers which are used to decrypt. They receiver decrements their random number list by one.

Clearly, the messages will always be shorter than the list of numbers generated by the PRNG.

I don't know if keeping lists of true random numbers is a storage issue and whether this scheme saves much storage. However, it would only require 1 random number per message instead of potentially hundreds for any given message.

The PRNG could be on a local PC, smart phone or on the net.

The scheme would get complex with multiple communicators since each would need a list of seeds for their communication only and each would be decremented with each message.

I believe it would extend the time before periodicity appears. In this sense it would be a more efficient use of random numbers. Whether security is compromised or is worse than a true OTP is beyond me.

Comment: What you've described is basically a stream cipher. The security rests on the security of the PRNG. It is possible to brute force the "seed" / shared secret and then test if the decryption using the resulting  key stream will generate a logical plaintext. If it does then you've found the seed with high probability. As such, it is not perfectly secure.

Comment: Beware that practically speaking, a PRNG isn't that good a stream cipher either. Any changes in the PRNG **implementation** e.g. when it comes to outputting bits or reseeding would suddenly generate a different stream. But that's more the developer in me speaking.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. So the weakness is that essentially the attacker can reproduce the encoding numbers by brute force attack on the PRNG using different seeds and determining if the deciphered text makes sense. I reason that the strength of the OTP is that the source numbers can only guessed at since they are truly random and each message uses a new set. Hence no information is leaked between messages.

Comment: Do stream ciphers rely on a shared set of seeds and how is this managed?

Comment: They rely on the randomness of the shared keys. Symmetric keys and seeds are used interchangeably in the described case (generally a seed has a more loose definition, they do not necessarily have to be fully random - they just need to contain enough entropy in total).

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting. How are the keys managed? I assume they are sequentially used and deleted? What happens when they are exhausted? Thanks again.

Comment: Key management is a topic all in itself but in your case the terms Diffie-Hellman and "key encapsulation" are probably in order if you want to replenish keys. Look up ratchets for a purely symmetric method. And yes, you can pre-share them as well.